# Orbeon builder collapses sections after a certain number of input fields

Tags: builder, orbeon

I'm having difficulties with Orbeon builder. Maybe it's a bug, but anyway... When I create a large form, after a certain number of input fields/rows Orbeon builder automatically collapses all sections except the first one. This is visible only when I reenter the form and from then on. To better illustrate this behavior 
[see the attached video](https://screenpresso.com/=C7mwg)

The form itself on frontend isn't collapsed and looks as it is intended. The same goes for the "Test" view. Just to mention that it doesn't matter how I set the "Collapsible" option for each section, they always get collapsed. It's very important to us to have the look/behavior in the Orbeon builder match the one on the frontend and test view. Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As very large forms were making Form Builder slower, we collapse sections past a certain numbers of controls. You can configure this with [this property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-builder.html#closing-sections):

`<property
    as="xs:integer"
    name="oxf.fb.section.close"
    value="100"/>`

You can try increasing that value to a larger number.

However, this should not impact the Test view. If the Test view is impacted, it is a bug.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Everything now looks as intended :). Thank you.